# How to check if multiple Row entries has Indicator Variable

Tags: python, pandas

I want to check if each unique Letter has a "1" somewhere in its duplicate row entries
below is a example of the DataFrame

```
  Letter  Indicator
0      A       0
1      A       1
2      A       0
3      B       0
4      B       0
5      C       0
6      C       0
7      C       1
8      C       0
```

So I want to return the Letter where the entries does not have a 1. In this example the letter B

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated

Thank you !

Comment: please edit your question to provide the data as **text** (and the expected output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If performance is important use [`numpy.setdiff1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) between unique values in original and filtered values:

```
out = np.setdiff1d(df['Letter'].unique(), df.loc[df['Indicator'].eq(1), 'Letter'].unique())
```

Or test membership by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with invert mask by `~`:

```
out = df.loc[~df['Letter'].isin(df.loc[df['Indicator'].eq(1), 'Letter']), 'Letter'].unique()
```

Or use [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html), but change `eq(1)` to `ne(1)` or `eq(0)`:

```
m = df['Indicator'].ne(1).groupby(df['Letter']).all()
#alternative
#m = df['Indicator'].eq(0).groupby(df['Letter']).all()
out = m.index[m]
```

For list use:

```
out = out.tolist()
```

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful! (I can't accept the answer yet) What resource would you recommend for these types of problems? (I have a lot of data work like this)

Comment: @Anrich - I think if need some filtrations like `df.loc[df['Indicator'].eq(1), 'Letter']` first and then combinations `numpy` functions like [numpy.setdiff1d](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html), [numpy.intersect1d](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html)... should be way for good performance solutions here

Answer (score 1):

You can `groupby` letter and check for the presence of 1:

```
(df.groupby('Letter')
   .filter(lambda g: 1 not in g['Indicator'].values)
   ['Letter'].unique()
   .tolist()
)
```

Or this alternative:

```
s = df['Indicator'].eq(1).groupby(df['Letter']).any()
list(s[~s].index)
```

output:

```
['B']
```

Comment: ya, I like also `groupby.filter`, but for really poor performance never use it.

Comment: @jezrael I also provided an alternative

Comment: It is much better solution. ;)